# Using SQL query to return data within MDX query

Tags: sql, mdx

I created a report that returns, among other things, species of trees our company uses to make wood products. My query returns in this format: `Species.Doug Fir`. This is, of course, how the data is listed in the table. I'm 99.9% certain that there is no way to "remove" the "species." and just leave the name of the species with the MDX query.

However, the sql query I was given to create this report from has the "species." removed and the project managers want this repeated here as well.

So is there a way to either remove the first part within the MDX query, or is there a way to (and here is where this may not make sense) create an SQL stmt within the MDX query to return the same data but allow me to remove that first part.

Comment: Should have access to a SUBSTRING/etc function, and offset the start by however long "species." is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing what your dimensions/levels/members are called, but try this:
`Replace([Tree Type].[Softwoods].currentMember.caption, "Species.", "")`
I'm using VBA string functions which MDX allows in Microsoft Analysis Services.